# Regularly Archiving Data to Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a database – call it `Jacob`. Every day a SQL Agent job copies all records older than 15 days to another database called `Jacob_Archive`

I would like to move `Jacob_Archive` to Azure, I’ve created a database with the tables, but when I try to move the data I get:

> Msg 40515, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
>   Reference to database and/or server name in 
>   Jacob_Archive.dbo.MasterResults` is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Please advise

Comment: Azure SQL Database doesn't support three part name queries (nor four). You'll need need to remove the database name from all of your queries: `dbo.MasterResults`

Comment: What is your actual mechanism for moving the data?  pure TSQL?  Are you using a linked server?  Using an SSIS package would be more appropriate for this considering you are moving the data to the cloud.

Comment: I was indeed using T-SQL - I'll look at SSIS, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Jacob_Archive database you need create an External Data Source that makes reference to the source database.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE RemoteReferenceData
WITH
(
    TYPE=RDBMS,
    LOCATION='myserver.database.windows.net',
    DATABASE_NAME='ReferenceData',
    CREDENTIAL= SqlUser
);
```

Then create External Tables for all tables on the source database that you want to archive data.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[zipcode](
    [zc_id] int NOT NULL,
    [zc_cityname] nvarchar(256) NULL,
    [zc_zipcode] nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    [zc_country] nvarchar(5) NOT NULL
)
WITH
(
    DATA_SOURCE = RemoteReferenceData
);
```

Then extract all the data you want from the remote table using an [elastic query](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/?wt.mc_id=MVP). You can create a stored procedure to extract the data you want to archive and put it on a table located on the Jacob_Archive database.

Once you have extracted the information you can run a stored procedure on the source table to remove the archived data. You can create an [schedule task](https://www.rdx.com/blog/azure-automation-scheduling-stored-procedures) to perform/run both stored procedures using Azure Automation.